# Using the Rule of 72 to compute residual income?

Tags: portfolio, investment-strategies, apr, fixed-income

Often I check an investment strategy's performance by summing the year-to-date realized gains/losses.

I take the sum of all closing(or market for unrealized) values **CT**, subtract the sum of all cost basises (sp?) **OT**, and divide that difference by the total cost basis **OT**.  That gives me raw performance year-to-date.  So in terms of percentage gain/loss:

```
performancePercYTD =  ((CT - OT) / OT - 1) * 100
```

From there it can be roughly annualized into an APR performance `= performancePercYTD * 365.25 / day_of_year`

Question.
Using the [Rule of 72](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/ruleof72.asp#axzz1pTSvv0D0) how can one estimate:

- The doubling frequency in days
- Projected portfolio value in 90 days
- How long before at this pace, the account will reach $10000
- How long before the first sustainable $500/month withdrawal *indefinitely* will not deplete the principal, assuming the current growth rate continues?
- The reverse of the last question, for example, what minimum amount could be a sustainable monthly withdrawal in 24 months(730.5 days)?

It's an exercise I would like to script for daily computations, since of course variables change constantly.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm beginning to realize there is a fundamental flaw in the way I've calculated my portfolio growth rate.  `OT` above is the sum of all costs, included the same dollar that has already been used to own & release many different equities over time.  What I probably need to is figure out somehow what was the account's _starting_ value on Jan 1st, and then account for all external deposits and withdrawals since, not related to trading or dividends or margin interest fees.

Comment: [Solving for the period needed to double money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money#Example_3:_Solving_for_the_period_needed_to_double_money)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your investment is growing at the rate of x% per period, then after n periods, it will have grown by a factor of (1+x/100)^n.  This formula also applies when n is not an integer. So, the investment will double in value for whatever n is the solution to
the equation

> 2 = (1+x/100)^n

If you take logarithms on both sides and solve the equation, you can get the
exact value of n.  The *Rule of 72* gives a *very good approximation* to the exact
answer: it says that

> the investment will double in value in 72/x periods.

If the
period is an year, multiply 72/x by 365.25 to get the doubling period in days.

---

The projected value in 3 months cannot be obtained directly from the Rule
of 72.  If your annualized growth rate is x%, then after three months you
should expect the value to have increased by a factor of

> (1 + x/400).

---

It is impossible to say when the investment will have value $100,000
without specifying the initial value.  Taking the initial value to be
P, we have to solve for n in the equation

> 100000 = P(1+x/100)^n

Once again, the Rule of 72 is not directly applicable, but we can fake
it a bit. If P = 100, the increase is by a factor of 1000, slightly less
than 1024 = 2^10.  The investment will double in value each 72/x periods,
and so increase by a factor of 1024 in 720/x periods.  So, the exact
value of n is somewhat smaller than 720/x periods in this example.

---

If your investment is generating x% gain each year, or (x/12)% gain
each month, you can withdraw $500 per month without depleting principal
as long as your investment has value I at least as large as the solution to

> I(x/1200) = 500, that is, I is at least 600,000/x

So, now that you know what I needs to be, if you start out with
P, you can figure out how long it will take to reach I using the
formulas above.  From that point on, you can withdraw $500/month
in perpetuity without reducing the value of your investment.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer. For simplicity I chose continuous compounding, being a portfolio with irregular and frequent asset&value changes, unlike CODs with steady interest rates etc. 72/x is a fine heuristic for quick mental estimates though for computers the actual formula [Years = ln(2) / rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72) is not less convenient. In my question I used arbitrary number values for clarity although the variables will interest me more when coding.  So in your reply to part2, by (1 + x/400) you meant (1 + (90/365.25) * x/100), correct?

Comment: You might want to use 91/365.25, but if you take 3 months to mean a quarter, then x/400 is pretty close to the number you want (technically, you need to use 1+y/100 where (1+y/100)^4 = 1 + x/100 but 1+x/400 is a good enough approximation to 1+y/100 and easier to compute.